# Ruby on Rails - Paginação de relação com active record e kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Estou estudando Ruby On Rails e como meta de aprendizado fiz uma API com as funcionalidades do básicas do Instagram.

Estou uma dificuldade em paginar os resultados da minha lista de seguires, também queria exibir apenas os seguires e não os dados do user como está no retorno abaixo:

Obs: estou usando a gema kaminari para paginação

**Método do meu controller**

```
def followeres
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])

    render json: @user, include: [:followers]
end
```

**Model User**

```
has_many :follows

has_many :follower_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower

has_many :following_relationships, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following
```

[...]

**Retorno atual**

```js
{
    "user": {
        "username": "teste123",
        "full_name": "Teste 123",
        "profile_pic_url": null,
        "genre": null,
        "phone": "41922222222",
        "email": "example@domain.com",
        "bio": null,
        "website": null,
        "is_private": 1,
        "is_verified": 0,
        "followers_count": 48,
        "following_count": 31,
        "followers": [
            {
                "username": "milagro_ullrich",
                "full_name": "Lance Bartell",
                "followers_count": 42,
                "following_count": 37,
                "is_private": 0
            },
            {
                "username": "geoffrey_howell",
                "full_name": "Jordon Ritchie",
                "followers_count": 34,
                "following_count": 38,
                "is_private": 0
            },
            [...]
        ]
    }
}
```

Minha tentativa, porém não pagina

```
def followeres

    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])

    @user.follower_relationships
    .page(params[:page] || 1)
    .per(1)
    .order('created_at DESC')

    render json: @user, include: [:followers]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Atualização...

Eu alterei meu controller para o código abaixo e está paginando agora...

```
def followeres

        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])

        @followers = @user.follower_relationships
        .page(params[:page] || 1)
        .per(params[:per_page] || 20)
        .order('created_at DESC')

        render json: { followers: @followers }, status: :ok

end
```

Porém não está retornando os dados do usuário como username, name etc.. que está configurado no serializer.

Resposta:

```
{
    "followers": [
        {
            "id": 3020,
            "user_id": 293,
            "following_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2019-07-25T19:22:37.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2983,
            "user_id": 63,
            "following_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2019-07-25T19:22:37.000Z"
        },
        [....]
    ]
}
```